# Please help debug this ASP.Net [VB] code. Trying to write to text file from SQL Server DB

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, text-files

I am a PHP programmer. I have no .Net coding experience (last seen it 4 years ago). Not interested in code-behind model since this is a quick temporary hack.

What I am trying to do is generate an output.txt file whenever the user submits new data. So an output.txt file if exists should be replaced with the new one.

I want to write data in this format :

```
123|Java Programmer|2010-01-01|2010-02-03
124|VB Programmer|2010-01-01|2010-02-03
125|.Net Programmer|2010-01-01|2010-02-03
```

I don't know VB, so not sure about string manipulations. Hope a kind soul can help me with this. I will be grateful to you. Thank you :)

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>

<script language="vb" runat="server">
  sub Page_Load(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)

  Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=winsqlus04.1and1.com;Initial Catalog=db28765269;User Id=dbo2765469;Password=ByhgstfH;") 
  Dim myCommand As SqlCommand
  Dim dr As SqlDataReader

  Dim FILENAME as String = Server.MapPath("Output4.txt")

    Dim objStreamWriter as StreamWriter
   ' If Len(Dir$(FILENAME)) > 0 Then Kill(FILENAME)
    objStreamWriter = File.AppendText(FILENAME)

   Try
   sqlConn.Open()
   'opening the connection
   myCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT  id, title, CONVERT(varchar(10), expirydate, 120) AS [expirydate],CONVERT(varchar(10), creationdate, 120) AS [createdate] from tblContact where flag = 0 AND ACTIVE = 1", sqlConn)
  'executing the command and assigning it to connection 
  dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader()

  While dr.Read()

    objStreamWriter.WriteLine("JobID: " & dr(0).ToString())
    objStreamWriter.WriteLine("JobID: " & dr(2).ToString())
    objStreamWriter.WriteLine("JobID: " & dr(3).ToString())

  End While
  dr.Close()
  sqlConn.Close()
  Catch x As Exception
  End Try

    objStreamWriter.Close()

    Dim objStreamReader as StreamReader
    objStreamReader = File.OpenText(FILENAME)

    Dim contents as String = objStreamReader.ReadToEnd()

    lblNicerOutput.Text = contents.Replace(vbCrLf, "<br>")

    objStreamReader.Close()
  end sub
</script>

<asp:label runat="server" id="lblNicerOutput" Font-Name="Verdana" />
```

Comment: Yeah, username, database name and the password are all fake from the start. Thank you for all the help ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .Net's [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) feature:

```
objStreamWriter.WriteLine("{0}|{1}|{2:yyyy-MM-dd}|{3:yyyy-MM-dd}", _
                          dr(0),  dr(1), dr(2), dr(3))
```

---

Some notes on your current code:

- (**EDIT**) You have an empty `Catch` block (`Catch x As Exception End Try`) which is silently swallowing any errors.  You should *never* do that.
- [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) is frowned upon.  Your `objStreamWriter` would be better named `writer` or `fileWriter`.
- You don't need to convert the dates to `VARCHAR`s on the server; you can output them in that format by using the [datetime format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) `yyyy-MM-dd` (As in my sample, or as `dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`
- `File.AppendText` will append to an existing file.  Are you sure you don't want to call [`File.CreateText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext.aspx), which will automatically erase the file if it already exists?
- You should close your objects using the [`Using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx), like this:

```
Using objStreamWriter As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(FILENAME)
    ...
End Using
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt reply. I tried dr(0).., nothing is written to the output.txt file. It is just blank :( Is my while loop ok?

Comment: I changed the name of the db, user, pass while posting this!

Thank you thank you thank you thank you soo much sir. It worked like magic! Took the Catch block off, followed your suggestions and boom, it works!

Now, I should process this text file using PHP (load Infile..). I know the whole PHP/.Net link is messy, but 1and1 shared hosting sucks big time.